# Who're the archangels, come season 8?

Tags: supernatural

Towards the end of season 8 Dean and Sam find:

> Metatron

Who references when talking to Naomi, what first happened when god left, to paraphrase, that "You Archangels" schemed and tried to extract information from him.

Am I mistaken in thinking he refers to Naomi/others as an Archangel?

Answer (score 2):

Naomi isn't an archangel. No archangel would be afraid of Crowley, and in their several standoffs she seemed unsure of herself. He was firing bullets made of angelblade metal, and if she were an archangel this wouldn't phase her a bit... she'd smite him while shrugging that off. However, she ran.

There may be no archangels left at all by this point, save Lucifer and Michael trapped in the Cage.

Comment: Just adding something, Naomi was an High Ranked Angel, similar to Castiel upon his first revival, but still less than a Seraph